# "ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1))" for a simple Ruby function

Tags: ruby, bash

So I'm writing a simple Ruby program, essentially a simple ORM. On my "delete" method, I have written the following:

```
file = "/Users/john/Projects/csv-orm/20180922-test.csv"

def delete id
  counter = 0
  csv = []

  CSV.foreach(file) do |row|
    counter += 1
    if counter != id
      csv << row
    end
  end

  counter = 0

  CSV.foreach(file, "w") do |row|
    row = csv[counter]
  end
end

delete 2
```

...and I'm running it in an irb session on my terminal (Mac OS X 10.13, ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin17]) to test it (for example, by pasting in the code above, and then trying `delete 2`, where the number `2` is the argument passed in for the id parameter), and I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    4: from /Users/apickle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
    3: from (irb):23
    2: from (irb):19:in `delete'
    1: from /Users/apickle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/csv.rb:1139:in `foreach'
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1))
```

Just to get it out of the way, I have tried testing it in a freshly exited and reopened irb session, and I am typing in `require "csv"` when I start it up. I'm not sure what to do. :/

EDIT:  I've renamed the function to `destroy` and `flfllgpt`, and I get the same result - and I have made a simple function that takes a single integer named `id` and `puts`s it. That function works. It seems to be somehow related to the CSV calls... when I comment those blocks out, it doesn't throw that to me. But I've used them before, too!

Comment: Your Ruby version is? Also add the full error stack please.

Comment: Is `file` an off-camera method? Please indicate the line at which the exception was raised. It’s best to avoid method names that are the same as a Ruby built-in method.

Comment: The error message tells you what line the error occurs on and what method the error occurs in. Since you don't tell us that information, despite being asked three times, it is more or less impossible to help you, sorry. Also, please research how to write a [mcve]. Your example is not complete, it is missing the definition of `file` and how you call `delete`. I also suspect that your example is not minimal; I'm guessing the problem can be demonstrated in less than 5 lines. And lastly, the logic of your code is unclear. What does `counter` do at the end? It is always 0, so what does it count?

Comment: @JörgWMittag I appreciate it! I have updated my post to include your critiques (and those of others above), I now point `file` to an appropriate file representing its use in my program, and I've included how I call `delete` in the area where I define it. Turns out `counter` at the end there is supposed to iterate... I just hadn't added the `counter += 1` code yet...

Comment: You need to make `file` a constant or instance variable, as local variables go out of scope when the method definition begins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to diagnose the problem without the exact error message, which includes the line number where the error occurs, the method in which the error occurs, the method call for which the error occurs, and the stack trace.

However, there is exactly *one* place in the code you posted where a method is called with 2 arguments:

```
CSV.foreach(file, "w") do |row| 
  # …
end
```

And indeed, [the documentation for `CSV::foreach`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach) clearly says that `CSV::foreach` only takes *one* positional argument, this *must* be the culprit. There simply is no other place in your code that could possibly raise this exception.

Comment: This is indeed it, I tried it... and that's what the culprit was. My mistake! I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess  CSV.foreach(file, "w") is the culprit here, because I think what you want to do is open a new file and then write the result? Check this out: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach

If changing it does not help, can you post the full error message? That makes it easier to identify the error.

Comment: I appreciate it! I have come to the same conclusion, in fact - the CSV.foreach method does not appear to have a second argument for "write" mode, I think it's purely for reading.